# Vaadin label content too big

Tags: vaadin

I have this piece of code

```
private VaadinLabel email, 
this.email = new VaadinLabel();
this.informativoDab = new VaadinLabel();
HorizontalLayout row = new HorizontalLayout();
row.setWidth("100%");
row.addComponent(this.email);
row.addComponent(this.informativoDab);
```

And it gives me this:

[image]

When I actually want this:

[image]

It should be simple to do, but I've tried doing

```
this.email.setWidth("50%");
```

and it didn't work.
How can I do this with Vaadin Label, since I also need a hint to show the entire e-mail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should actually use "100%" as the label size as it should take all the space the layout gives for it, half in this case.

By default Vaadin will then wrapt the text on multiple lines. IIRC there isn't a built in css style name to do it, so you'll need to use CSS to disable wrapping and use the ellipsis to visualise overflown text. You could e.g. use "cut_text" style name (*email.addStyleName("cut_text")*) for your email label along with following css rules to your theme:

```
.cut_text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I understand it should have worked, but it didn't :(
I inspected the element and edited to test it, but it remains with the same behavior. It doesn't even wrap the text on multiple lines

Comment: It worked now. I had to add 'overflow: hidden'. Thank you, mstahv and @okolimar

Comment: Completed the answer with overflow:hidden

Answer (score 0):

as @mstahv mentioned, add a style name to your label

```
email.addStyleName("cut_text");
```

and use that css he wrote

```
.cut_text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

as for the whole email to be displayed, I would suggest adding a description. Then when user hovers the hidden email it will popup in a small tooltip.

```
email.setDescription("very_long@email.com");
```